# Verify if substring included in string when comparing away elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, substring

I have two data sets

```
example1 = ["og", "phan"]
example2 = ["dog", "cat", "elephant", "chicken", "snake"]
```

What I need to be returned, exactly, is a new array containing elements from `example1` **only** if they are substring of any of the elements of `example2` **and** they should also be included **in the same order** as they were presented.

I managed to get the following code working, but the new array returns the elements in a different order (e.g. `["phan", "og"]` instead of `["og", "phan"]`.

```
r = []
array1.map { |x| r.push(x) if array2.join(" ").include?(x) }
r.flatten
```

Extra:  I found out that `include?` does not work if you use it when comparing array against array, in other words, it does not find substring within string in a single array element unless it is exactly the same.

Comment: When I tried your code, the order was right. check out and run: https://repl.it/EA98/0

Comment: Indeed, but I was missing the sort method at the end, that is why it did not return the array in the proper order.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this

```
example1.select { |syllable| example2.any? { |word| word.include? syllable } }
```

Comment: It's more a substring than a syllable.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know how to name it.

Comment: It works.  Thanks You. I forgot to mention that the function did not work because it needed to be returned in a lexicographic order, which is simply done by calling sort

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)